# adapt url calls in javascript to /~userdir/ automatically

Tags: javascript, apache, url

I'm working on a web app project shared on svn with many people, and we all have our test working folders on http://base-url/~username.

In certain javascript files, I call local urls (for autocompletion, for example), using the '/my/url' syntax. In the above setup, however, the url would work as '~username/my/url'. If I commit such code, however, each person has to change the values every time they update. How can I dynamically add the prefix to the files?

thanks,
manojo

Answer (score 0):

With **window.location.pathname** you can get the path of the current page (so /~username/eventual/subfolders). So you can get the prefix based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be using relative urls and not absolute.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are right, absolute urls do not work. However, I am using a framework (cakephp), which re-routes urls. This means that the relative url in my case changes depending on the page on which I am. I guess the above solution would be a temporary fix for me, although I am not sure if there are better solutions.